# Visual studio ignores AdditionalLibraryDirectories in props file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to build the application that uses libzip.
I build the libzip library first and got **zip.lib** and **zip.dll**.
Now on the linking stage I get an error

> Error LNK1104 cannot open file 'zip.lib'

It seems that *AdditionalLibraryDirectories* is ignores whereas *AdditionalIncludeDirectories* works well (all zip-related headers are found)

*settings.props:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" />
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup />
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$(SolutionDir)\libzip\lib;$(SolutionDir)\libzip\build;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>$(SolutionDir)\libzip\build\lib\Debug</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
      <AdditionalDependencies>kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib;comdlg32.lib;advapi32.lib;shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib;uuid.lib;odbc32.lib;odbccp32.lib;zip.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup />
</Project>
```

If I add *"$(SolutionDir)\libzip\build\lib\Debug\"* to *Additional library directories* of the project, **everything works**! So the zip library is not corrupted.

Comment: Make sure that the main project's setting contains %(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)

Comment: @HansPassant That's the answer! Thank you!